# SSRS 2005 report with multiple datasets need to change parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

All,

I've been working on a custom timesheet report that uses multiple datasets (8 to be exact). Each dataset selects the data by the same ID field which is currently input as a parameter. It works great like that. But now I'm told that the end user wants to input a date and have all the reports printed out for that date rather than having to enter in an ID each time. Each timesheet is 2 - 3 pages. It is intended to emulate a form and contains some data but a lot of blank areas to allow the field people to write in any changes that have occurred.

My question, is this: what is the best way of accommodating the new requirement? Should I build it all as one big dataset and use the date as a parameter?

Should I create a wrapper report that would prompt for the date and then use the existing report as sub report? Would that even work?

Is there any way I can just create a new date parameter and put that ahead of the ID parameter and get them to print out like that? I've got a few hidden parameter fields on the body that get used in the page header and are used to link some of the datasets.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is indeed by creating a wrapper report with the date parameter. The data set in this report will then fetch all items (with ID) that match the query by the user. The report can then have a list for that dataset, with the original report as a subreport. If you pass the ID parameter from the dataset to the subreport you wouldn't need to change hardly anything in the original report.

Two things to watch out for:

- the Report Header and Footer in a subreport are not rendered - these are only rendered for the wrapper report
- you may need to tweak your page breaks in the subreport and on the new list in the wrapper report so each new form starts on a fresh page

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting one record. I'm not seeing the multiple reports I would expect.

Comment: It should work. You'll need to provide some code (SQL for the wrapper) and info on the parameter to get more help from us.

Comment: Thanks, I recreated the wrapper report, and put the sub report in the  (except for removing the unused columns since I need them as  page header so I'm keeping them in a group header) But the header is not repeating when the subreport changes even though I had repeat group header checked.. <GRRRR>

I tried putting it in a page header but that was a no go either. Where should I put the fields I need to show as a repeat header?

Comment: The header thing is probably a new issue for you. You should have a peek at other questions on this topic, and post a new question with enough details if you can't work it out. Good luck!